# WHM VPS for single site, only 1 ip. How to dedicate it?

Tags: ip, vps, ssl-certificate

I have a VPS with WHM/cPanel (11.38) installed on it. I only have 1 IP and I won't be able to get any more. The VPS will only have 1 site on there.

I need to install a SSL certificate for the website, but I require a dedicated IP (as the SNI SSLs [wont work on WinXP IE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) among others). I know this was possible a few years back on dedicated servers as I did this before but honestly cannot remember how.

Is there a way for set the main "shared" ip to be dedicated to the one site on there?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I am aware this is not possible via the WHM UI, the answer is seek is for how I can do this manually via eg. ssh or similar. Thank you!

Comment: Questions concerning the use of shared web hosting by end users or resellers, rather than the administration of web hosting, are off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do it manually. The problem with WHM/CPanel is they expect things to be done a certain way so there is no way around trying to get WHM to accept the shared IP as a dedicated IP.

Comment: I remember when I did it I was manually as well via SSH, but I simply cannot remember how. Any pointers in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: I asked this question on the cpanel forums as well and gave me more or less the same answer as you, so I will mark this as the answer :).
(Link to thread: http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/dedicated-ip-workaround-whm-1-ip-353482.html) - Thanks for the help, appreciate it!